# Android: scale animation does not work when direction is changed

Tags: android, xml, scale, android-animation

In my Android app, I hava a scale animation.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"   android:fillEnabled="true"  android:fillAfter="true"  >
 <scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"   android:fromYScale="1.0"    android:toYScale="1.0"      android:duration="32000"   />
 </set>
```

it works fine. it scales the view from left to right. but I need to scale from right to left. so when I modify the `fromXScale="-1.0"`, the animation does not happen and the view is scaled instantly without animation.
My animation xml for the reverse direction is given below:

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"   android:fillEnabled="true"  android:fillAfter="true"  >            
  <scale android:fromXScale="-1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"   android:fromYScale="1.0"    android:toYScale="1.0"      android:duration="32000"   /> 
 </set>
```

How can I animate the View from reverse direction? what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Pivot solved the problem. Its a better practice to control direction of an animation through pivotX and pivotY.

Answer (score 1):

You should also add a `android:fillBefore="true"` in your animation.

The in the forward animation your view usually will have a scale of 1 which mean you don't need to set it at start. But in the reverse animation you start at default (ie 1) and animate to... 1